# how can I save password(login info) using selenium , so I have to not login again and again on Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

### **my project**

I am working on a project in which I have login on Instagram  again and again , and after a limited number of login . I can not no more login for a day.

### **my problem**

is there any way I can save login information and do not have login every time .

### **My research**

I found some solution but its in java , and do not know java so well ,I want in solution in python - [I found solution in java](https://forum.knime.com/t/selenium-webdriver-profile-save-and-save-password-how-is-it-done/23416)

my browser - Firefox

python - latest

selenium - latest

Answer (score 2):

### I found the solution:

you need to add profile to `add argument` you can do this either by making a new profile of chrome or add existing

### steps of solution in python

1. make a new folder for chrome profile or u can go to
   `example of my path - "C:\Users\saksh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3"`
   and take existing path of chrome profile

2.this the code of python which u have to add

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" +add ur folder path either new folder or existing profile+ ")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options =  options , executable_path = "ur chrome driver path" )
```

3. if u made a new folder the first time u have to login and save password.

---

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

instead of inspecting the element you can use an extension called Katalon Recorder which will usually 100% get the xpath of the *thing* you are trying to interact with. for example:
you cannot inspect the favorites bar, but using Katalon Recorder you can fetch the xpath, its also good for more efficient selenium coding

Comment: using this you can make selenium click passwords, save passwords. but I'm pretty sure when using selenium you will not be logged into an account since it is an external webdriver automation